# If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=2$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n-n=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I was asked to prove/disprove the claim in the title.
I tried thinking about counterexamples but it didn't go quite well so I tried proving and got stuck. I'd like to have some feedbacks on how can I continue from here or if I'm completely out of path.
We want to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n-n=\infty$.
So we have to prove $\forall M>0$. $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $\forall n>N.$ $a_n>M$.
Let M>0. We have to choose $N$ that satisfy the desired.
$a_n-n > M \Leftrightarrow a_n>M+n$.
If we choose $\epsilon=1$ then there exists $N_{\epsilon}$ s.t $\forall n>N$ $a_n>2-1=1$.
Now we have to prove $a_n>M+n$
And we have in hand $a_n>1$
The choice of $\epsilon$ was completely random I was just trying to see if I can figure out something when plugging in a number

Comment: I would recommend analyzing the contrapositive:  Suppose that the limit of $a_n-n$ does not approach infinity (that is, there exists $M>0$ such that $a_n-n<M$ for all $n$).  Then, try to show that the limit on the left fails.

Comment: $a_n-n=n\Big(\frac{a_n}{n}-1\Big)$

Comment: Based on the comment from @Mittens, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n-n) = \left(\lim_{n\to\infty} n \right)\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}n - 1 \right) = \infty(2-1) = \infty$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If we choose $\epsilon=1$ then there exists $N_{\epsilon}$ s.t $\forall n>N$ $a_n>2-1=1$.

This is the line where you stumbled, by my account.  I will fix what could reasonably be considered typos, to give

> If we choose $\epsilon=1$ then there exists $N_{\epsilon}$ s.t $\forall n>N_\epsilon$, $\frac{a_n}n>2-1=1$.

This gives that for all $n > N_\epsilon$, we have $a_n - n > 0$.  That's not enough.  Let's shrink $\epsilon$ to $\epsilon = 1/2$:

> If we choose $\epsilon=1/2$ then there exists $N_{\epsilon}$ s.t $\forall n>N_\epsilon$, $\frac{a_n}n>2-\frac12=\frac32$.

This gives $a_n - n > \frac{n}2$ for all $n > N_\epsilon$.  This is enough to finish.  Can you do so?

> Note that $n > 2M$ gives $\frac{n}2 > M$.  In conjuction with the above, letting $n > \max(N_\epsilon, 2M)$ gives $$a_n-n > \frac{n}2 > M$$

Comment: As a sidenote: you've had three answers who all chose the same "$\epsilon = 1/2$".  There's no reason this $\epsilon$ was used except out of convenience ("$\epsilon = 1$ is too large, so what's the next nice positive number less than that?")  In fact, any $0 < \epsilon < 1$ would work just as well, with a slightly different solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes I had a typo after choosing the $\epsilon$, I meant the sequence $\frac{a_n}{n}$ and not $a_n$, just like you wrote. I appreciate the detailed proof, thank you again!.

Answer (score 2):

Since the first limit exist, for sufficiently large $n$ we have $$ |a_n - 2n| < n/2$$

Then $$|a_n -n|= |a_n-2n+n| \ge n -|a_n - 2n| > n/2  $$